# What does green dot with A in Eclipse mean?

Tags: eclipse

I don't know what this green dot means:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rgBj.png]

Its related to Abstract and that is all I know

Answer (score 1):

It means the member is public.

http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm?cp=1_4_12

Comment: And also abstract.

Comment: As you guessed, that's what the A means.